# Android Sqlite and Multicolumns issue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-sqlite

i have simple project with sqlite (send and retrive info for 3 columns). It works good. Actually i try to put those info to listView with 3 columns adapter -> it looks like this:
[image]

But when i run my app, my adapter duplicate the same three times, after this it step for next column and make the same. 
[image]

What im trying to do is fill textView2 info from column nr 1, textView3 from column nr 2...

This is code for building ArrayList and call for Listview and adapter:

```
private void populateListView() {
    Cursor data = mDatabaseHelper.getData();
    ArrayList<String> listData = new ArrayList<>();
    while (data.moveToNext()) {
        listData.add(data.getString(1));
        listData.add(data.getString(2));
        listData.add(data.getString(3));
    }

    ListDataAdapter adapter = new ListDataAdapter(this, R.layout.adapter_view_layout, listData);
    mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

and for Adapter:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.LayoutRes;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;



class ListDataAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private static final String TAG = "ListDataAdapter";
    private Context mContext;
    int mResource;

    public ListDataAdapter(@NonNull Context context, @LayoutRes int resource, @NonNull ArrayList<String> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        mContext = context;
        mResource = resource;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        String name = getItem(position).toString();
        String sex = getItem(position).toString();
        String date = getItem(position).toString();


        LayoutInflater inflater =  LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(mResource,parent, false);


        TextView tvName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        TextView tvSex = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        TextView tvDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);

        tvName.setText(name);
        tvDate.setText(date);
        tvSex.setText(sex);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you are setting the same `String` on the three `TextView`s, so that is expected. 
So, to achieve what you wish, you'd have to create a new class that holds those 3 columns. Let's name it `RowModel`. So instead of working with `String`s, you'd work with your new class. Something like this:

```
private void populateListView() { 
    Cursor data = mDatabaseHelper.getData();
    ArrayList<RowModel> listData = new ArrayList<>();
    while (data.moveToNext()) {
        listData.add(new RowModel(data.getString(1), data.getString(2), data.getString(3));
    } 

    ListDataAdapter adapter = new ListDataAdapter(this, R.layout.adapter_view_layout, listData);
    mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Then your adapter would be like this:

```
class ListDataAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RowModel> {

    @NonNull 
    @Override 
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        RowModel model = getItem(position);
        String name = model.getName();
        String sex = model.getSex();
        String date = model.getDate();

        // populate TextViews
    }
}
```

Comment: Eduard any suggestions how the "Rowmodel" class should looks like?

Comment: It can be a simple POJO with 3 fields.